# I got a confusion about some URLs that I see on the Internet

Tags: url

Please tell me the difference between "someSite.com/something" and "something.someSite.com". Are they equivalent? As an amteur programmer, I know how to do the former. I think that I may need to learn network administration to be able to do the latter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's usually referred to as a subdomain. This is the over simplified version:

You have a DNS server that converts the domain to an IP. That DNS server also handles subdomains. usually www is synonymous with the base domain itself. You can have more subdomains also, like sub.domain.something.someSite.com/something

You can make them resolve to the same or different IPs, depending on their purpose.

Even if they resolve to the same IP, the web server at that IP receives a request that includes the original domain name. So on that same IP, the server can give different responses for each domain. This is usually the case with small hosting packages, as they can have thousands of domains on a single IP and they all serve up different websites from different clients.

Comment: So I need to speak to the OS or network admin for the latter! Right?

Comment: Most hosting plans come with tools to setup subdomains. CPanel is popular and you can set up a subdomain there. It gives you the option to specify another directory to load for that subdomain, or you can use the same directory as your original site.

Answer (score 1):

`someSite.com/something` is from technical point of view a file on the server, while `something.someSite.com` is a subdomain, which could link to a completely different webserver.

In most cases, the two variants does give you the identical content, because both of them are server-side linked to the same page.